# Change Object name of spawn object to client and server depending on the localplayer ID (Unity 3d Unet)

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity3d-unet

I have a gameobject that is spawned via Networkserver.spawn(missile). I want to change the object name of the spawn missile depending on the local player name but it is always taking the server player name. i already used the [command] to send data to server and use [client] that contains server command to distribute to all clients.

Comment: please provide more details. code